# Hibernate parent/child association. Update parent make child lost all associated objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following classes.

```
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Address address;
    private Employer employer;
}

public class Employer {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}

public class Address {
    private int id;
}
public class Project{
    private int id;
}

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="me.hibernate.basic.xml.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string" />
        <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string" />
        <many-to-one name="address" column="address" unique="true" class="me.hibernate.basic.xml.Address"/>
        <set name="projects" cascade="save-update, delete-orphan" sort="natural">
            <key column="employee_proj_id" />
            <one-to-many class="me.hibernate.basic.xml.Project" />
        </set>
        <many-to-one name="employer" column="employer" class="me.hibernate.basic.xml.Employer"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>



<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="me.hibernate.basic.xml.Employer" table="EMPLOYER">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string" />
        <set name="employees" cascade="save-update, delete-orphan" table="EMPLOYEE">
            <key column="employer"/>
            <one-to-many class="me.hibernate.basic.xml.Employee" />
        </set> 
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="me.hibernate.basic.xml.Address" table="ADDRESS">
        <meta attribute="class-description"> This class contains the address detail. </meta>
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>  

  <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="me.hibernate.basic.xml.Project" table="PROJECT">
            <meta attribute="class-description"> This class contains the project detail. </meta>
            <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
                <generator class="native" />
            </id>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

In my application I create few Employees and assign an address to them. And add some projects. Then I create an employer and add all the employees to employer. Once I add employees and update the employer, all the employees lose their addresses and projects. How can I do this with keeping lazy loading feature. I don't need to set lazy="false".

```
Employee emp1 = ME.addEmployee("Zara", "Ali");
Employee emp2 = ME.addEmployee("Daisy", "Das");

Address addr1 = ME.addAddress(35, "xxxxxx Street", "XXXXX", "XY7 0ZZ");
Address addr2 = ME.addAddress(42, "xxxxxx Street", "XXXXX", "XY7 7ZZ");
ME.setAddress(emp1.getId(), addr1);
ME.setAddress(emp2.getId(), addr2);

Set<Project> proj = new HashSet<Project>();
proj.add(new Project("NOVA"));
proj.add(new Project("GTA Simplify"));
proj.add(new Project("Jazz"));

ME.addProjects(emp.getId(), proj);
ME.addProjects(emp.getId(), proj);
```

All working up to this point.

```
Set<Employee> emps = new HashSet<Employee>();
emps.add(emp1); emps.add(emp2);

//Add existing employees to employer - Many-to-one bidirectional
Employer employer = ME.addEmployer("XYZ");
ME.addEmployees(employer.getId(), emps);

public Integer addEmployees(Integer employerID, Set<Employee> employees) {
 Session session = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx = null;
    try {
      tx = session.beginTransaction();
      Employer employer = (Employer) session.get(Employer.class,employerID);
      employer.getEmployees().clear();
      employer.getEmployees().addAll(employees);
      session.update(employer);
      tx.commit();
  } catch (HibernateException e) {
     if (tx != null)
     tx.rollback();
     e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
     session.close();
  }
  return employerID;
}
```

Once I added employees, all the foreign key references are lost in the PROJECT.employee_proj_id and EMPLOYEE.address.

**Hibernate log:**

```
->Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set first_name=?, last_name=?, basic=?, address=?, employer=? where id=? 
->Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set first_name=?, last_name=?, basic=?, address=?, employer=? where id=? 
->Hibernate: update PROJECT set employee_proj_id=null where employee_proj_id=?
 ->Hibernate: update PROJECT set employee_proj_id=null where employee_proj_id=?
->Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set employer=? where id=? ->Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set employer=? where id=?
```

Comment: I can see below sql queries are triggered.
->Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set first_name=?, last_name=?, basic=?, address=?, employer=? where id=?
->Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set first_name=?, last_name=?, basic=?, address=?, employer=? where id=?
->Hibernate: update PROJECT set employee_proj_id=null where employee_proj_id=?
->Hibernate: update PROJECT set employee_proj_id=null where employee_proj_id=?
->Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set employer=? where id=?
->Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set employer=? where id=?

Comment: If I set Employer to Employee instead of adding set of Employees to Employer, It works properly. Both case hibernate update the employee records. But only when employees are added to the employer, employee lose their projects.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are clearing the employees before you add more employees, which is the root cause of everything. I'm not sure what you are doing when adding addresses, Project, employer etc., You need not clear the employees. If you have cascadetype.all set on the employees then saving the employer will update the newly added employees.

```
employer.getEmployees().clear();//remove this line.
employer.getEmployees().addAll(employees);
```